# VUe.js run serve failing after installation

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have installed Vue on my terminal with :

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

After that , I created a project, moved into the folder and tried to run the server :

```
vue create frontend
cd frontend
npm run serve
```

So , I didn't change anything from the presets but I can't launch my server and I get the following error :

```
  ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                              21:56:21

 error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

Syntax Error: RangeError: /home/simao/Desktop/chess_DB/frontend/src/App.vue: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)


 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-262 1:0-262 1:263-514 1:263-514
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.19:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I looked into App.vue and main.js but this feels strange since I haven't touched the files after installing vue. Any idea what it might be ?

Vue version : @vue/cli 4.5.15

node : v16.14.0

OS : Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What version of node are you using? `node -v`

Comment: @Djave hi, this : v16.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Thats cannot be a problem but maybe is difference between 'npm runserve' and 'npm run serve' command?